# Basic questions about convex optimization

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization

I have some basic questions about convex optimization.

1. From finding sources online, I've seen that many algorithms (for example, Newton's method) describe themselves as $o(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$.  What exactly does $\epsilon$ mean?  Does it mean that the point $x$ found by the algorithm is within $\epsilon$ distance of the optimal point $p$, or does it mean that $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ distance of $f(p)$?  If it's the later, is it a constant factor of $\epsilon$ (i.e. $f(x) + \epsilon \ge f(p)$) or is it a multiplicative factor of $\epsilon$ (i.e. $f(x) \ge (1 - \epsilon)f(p)$)?
2. I have seen convex optimization problems phrased as:

> Choose $x$ to minimize $f$ subject to $g_1(x) \le 0, \dots, g_n(x) \le 0$, where $f, g_1, \dots, g_n$ are all convex functions.

Do convex optimization algorithms find an approximate minimization of $f$ subject to the $g_j$ constraints?  Or do they find an approximate minimization of $f$ *that comes within $\epsilon$ of satisfying the $g_j$ constraints*?

And my final question: is there an online resource you can point me at that offers a gentle overview of convex optimization algorithms (not necessarily how they work, but more what they do) that might answer questions like the above?  If not online, a print resource would be helpful, too.  I've got access to a university library system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this [online course](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/EE364A) to be an excellent resource for understanding convex optimization. In particular they cover constraints early in the course and if you want to look at a simpler solution you can consider [linear dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_dynamical_system) to get a basic idea of what's happening.

I'm not sure exactly what $\epsilon$ is in this case but it's typically a small positive number. It may indicate "step size" in [gradient of descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) algorithms such as Newton's Method so that the algorithm takes longer to get to the local minimum when the step size is smaller, which is to say $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is bigger. If I had to guess I'd say $o(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ is constant time which takes longer with a smaller step size.